# Connect UISlider to fontSize

Tags: iphone, ios

Possible way connect UISlider to fontSize [ (IBAction)font1 and (IBAction)font2 ]. This is the code

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UISlider* fontSizeSlider;
    IBOutlet UITextView* textView;
}
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)sender;
-(IBAction)font1;
-(IBAction)font2;
@end
```

.m

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)sender
{
   textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"??????" size:sender.value];
}

-(IBAction)font1{
   textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Heiti TC" size:18];
}

-(IBAction)font2{
    textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:18];
}

-(IBAction)font1; //[UIButton]

-(IBAction)font1; //[UIButton]

-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged; //[UISlider]
```

Comment: Although I can't see the point in the last two methods, your first one should work fine. Have you defined the maximum and minimum values of your `UISlider`? What exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to choose from two fonts. So you must store the name of the font in a `NSString`. Something like this:

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UISlider* fontSizeSlider;
    IBOutlet UITextView* textView;
    NSString *currentFont;
}
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)sender;
-(IBAction)font1;
-(IBAction)font2;
@end
```

.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    currentFont = @"Heiti TC"; //Or whatever your default font is
    textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:currentFont size:sender.value];
}
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)sender
{
   textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:currentFont size:sender.value];
}

-(IBAction)font1{
   currentFont = @"Heiti TC";
   textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:currentFont size:fontSizeSlider.value];
}

-(IBAction)font2{
   currentFont = @"Marker Felt";
   textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:currentFont size:fontSizeSlider.value];
}
```

Comment: See my answer for a simpler approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain the font face being used, and just resize it when moving the slider, you can grab the existing font instance and pass it `fontWithSize:` to derive a new font instance with the same face:

```
-(IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider*)sender
{
   textView.font = [textView.font fontWithSize:sender.value];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly you are wanting to change the font size based on what the value of the slider is. Try this code out to change the font size based on the slider value:

```
- (IBAction)sliderChangeFontSize:(id)sender {
     textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Heiti TC" size:slider.value];
}
```

Then hook the IBAction to the Slider in the nib file and select the Sent Event as "Value Changed"

**OR**

With the method that you are using should work. The only problem is that you're going to have to connect the slider delegate to the View Controller so that way you are able to use the sender value.

Comment: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Heiti TC" size:slider.value]; , not One font , i wont more font > (IBAction)font1 and (IBAction)font2

Comment: So you are wanting to be able to change between the two fonts whenever the slider is being moved?